# OpenLayers 3 modify end event

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, events

I want to save the geometry data after I modify it, so I need an event that fire after I finish to modify the feature.
I use the following from this post: 
[listener modify interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726734/open-layers-3-how-to-create-listener-for-a-modify-interaction)

```
    var selected_features = select.getFeatures();
// when a feature is selected...
selected_features.on('add', function (event) {
    // get the feature
    var feature = event.element;
    feature.on("change", function (event) {
            logStatus(feature.getId() + " has been changed!\n");
    });
});
```

But this listener fires too many times in a single modification, and if I am using 'once' instead of 'on' its fires only the first little change and no more, so its not saving the real change.
I need something like "changeend" or "modifyend" that will fire when I will finish to modify the feature, what can i use?

Comment: This is a known limitation. A GitHub issue was created for that recently: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2946.

Answer (score 10):

If you need a modifyend event why dont you use it within the modify interaction.(I guess you use a modify interaction)
check this

```
modify.on('modifyend',function(e){
console.log("feature id is",e.features.getArray()[0].getId());
});
```

This event is available in the latest versions of ol3. In my code snip, I assume you only modify one fetaure at once (getArray()[0]) . If you use more than one fetaure to modify at once then get the fetaures array and add a loop for further manipulation. Like so:

```
modify.on('modifyend',function(e){
var features = e.features.getArray();
for (var i=0;i<features.length;i++){
console.log("feature changed id is",features[i].getId());
}
});
```

Comment: You should specify that `modify` is the name of the Modify Interaction and that your `modifyend` code comes after defining the Interaction : first `var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: select.getFeatures()
    });` and then your code. `select` is the name of my Select Interaction. Also a developer can do `e.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()` or `e.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getType()` to get the coords or the type. Nice answer anyway dude.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but with OL5 it would seem that `e.features.getArray()[0].getId())` always returns the same id whatever the feature I am modifying is. Would there be another way to know which feature has been changed?